# converting rtf files to pdf file format on solaris 10

Tags: java, shell, pdf, rtf, solaris-10

Unable to convert `.rtf` files to `.pdf` format on solaris 10. I read about itext, jasperreports, JODConverter:

1. `itext` - rtfparser is removed
2. `jasperreports` - rtfto pdf conversion is not available
3. `JODconverter` - internally it uses libreoffice but it requires solaris version 11 or greater.

I have been trying **Ted** which is a word processor, internally it access perl libraries. Even though I installed them it still throws errors such `libpcre` not found. Also, the `rtftopdf` script tries to access `libpng14` which is not available.

If anyone tried rtf to pdf conversion on solaris. Please do help me.
PS: We cannot upgrade solaris version

Comment: Are you willing to develop a software for this task? As you can do this with java which of course runs on solaris 10

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am trying for existing Java libraries or shell script. Can you please help me in choosing libraries.

Comment: I am not expert at unix but I would use a script in another environment in which that is easy to download your rtf files, convert, and upload to your solaris 10 box. This solution may take less time than doing it there.

Comment: Thank you. I have been trying ted(https://nllgg.nl/Ted/) but no luck with libraries for solaris 10.

Comment: @AnushaMaddali I recommend you to add the Version of your Solaris isntallation using "uname -a" and  also the Installed Package Version of your last update using "pkgparam -v SUNWvts | grep PRODVERS" this will give us a better understanding of your environment.

Answer (score 0):

I recently took the decision to bring back the JODConverter project to life (I own the jodconverter.org domain). I don't understand your statement #3. Have you tried JODConverter with OpenOffice ? According to https://www.openoffice.org/dev_docs/source/sys_reqs_30.html, Apache OpenOffice should work fine on Solaris 10 (I didn't test it though on this OS).

If you find a way to use JODConverter, don't cut on integration tests. RTF to PDF are (sadly) not the best results I got with JODConverter (Libre/Open Office).

If you can afford having an OpenOffice process running in background, its super easy to create PDF file from RTF file using JODConverter.